# C++ text file printing

Tags: c++, file

I'm attempting to read in a text file from user input, count the lines which gives me the width and the height and then print it out, my problem occurs when I'm printing out, instead of printing the correct output, it will print a lot of random symbols.

Input:

```
#################################################
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#                                               #
#################################################
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>  //declaring variables
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool working = true;
    int array_size = 2048; 
    char * array = new char[array_size]; 
    ifstream file;
    string infile;
    string line;
    int nodeCount = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    char c;

    int position = 0; //this will be used incremently to fill characters in the array 
  
                cout << "Please enter an input file: " << endl << "Test1.txt"<< endl << "Test2.txt"<< endl << "Test3.txt" << endl;
                cin >> infile;

            if(infile == "Test1.txt" || infile == "Test2.txt" || infile == "Test3.txt")
            {
                file.open(infile);

                            while(getline(file,line))
                            {
                                 
                                width = line.length();
                                position++;
                                height++;
                                

                            }
        
                            
        
                            for(int i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
                            {
                                cout << array[i];
                            }
                            
                        cout << endl << "Width: " << width << endl << "Height: " << height << endl;
            }

            else
                cout << "file error" << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You don't save input you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should comment this but I can't yet... But I miss where you fill the array.

Edit: I mean, you are reading in the variable `line`, but printing the array `array`.